# Order developer types alphabetically

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Please order the list of developer types alphabetically as sort order of position doesn't make sense.  The seniority drop down looks good as that order matters sense as you have an experience level:

Student->Junior->Lead->Manager etc...

But the developer type should be in alphabetical order as it has no sense of experience level / hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: I don't know that alphabetical is really the best way to do this. Full Stack/Front End/Back End Web really should go together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed and pushed to production. Thanks!